# What is $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_1^{1/x}+a_2^{1/x}+\dots+a_n^{1/x}}{b_1^{1/x}+b_2^{1/x}+\dots+b_n^{1/x}}\right)^x$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_1^{1/x}+a_2^{1/x}+\dots+a_n^{1/x}}{b_1^{1/x}+b_2^{1/x}+\dots+b_n^{1/x}}\right)^x$$
Can you try to do this limit without L'Hôpital's rule or Taylor expansion? Thank you for trying.

Comment: What do you know about the $a_i$'s and $b_j$'s?  Are they positive numbers?

Comment: It does not say anything about a1, a2,...,an. I think we can say they are real numbers.

Comment: My guess: the $a_i, b_i$ are positive numbers.  The answer should be given in terms of the $a_i, b_i$.

Comment: Ok. Let's say they are positive numbers. Do you have any idea how to do it? I was thinking about adding +1-1 in (...) cause we have 1^infinity but I do not know how to continue after that.

Comment: Hint.  First do special cases.  Can you do this?
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{2^{1/x}+3^{1/x}}{1^{1/x}+1^{1/x}}\right)^x = \sqrt{6}
$$

Comment: I think I can but what is the point?

Comment: When you can do simple ones, then work on more complicated ones.  Until you see a general method.

Comment: Ok but I already know i need to write them like (1+F(x))^x which will become e^(F(x)*x) but I do not know what to do after  that. Maybe that is not the way it should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of the derivative, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{1/x\to0}\frac{a^{1/x}-1}{1/x}
&=\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}a^t\,\right|_{t=0}\\
&=\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}e^{t\log(a)}\,\right|_{t=0}\\
&=\left.\vphantom{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}}\log(a)\,e^{t\log(a)}\,\right|_{t=0}\\[3pt]
&=\log(a)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, we have
$a_k^{1/x}=1+\log(a_k)/x+o\!\left(1/x\right)$ as $x\to\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{a_1^{1/x}+a_2^{1/x}+\cdots+a_n^{1/x}}{b_1^{1/x}+b_2^{1/x}+\cdots+b_n^{1/x}}\right)^x
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+\frac1n\log(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)/x+o\!\left(1/x\right)}{1+\frac1n\log(b_1b_2\cdots b_n)/x+o\!\left(1/x\right)}\right)^{\large x}\\[3pt]
&=\left(\frac{a_1a_2\cdots a_n}{b_1b_2\cdots b_n}\right)^{1/n}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: In which base is that log?

Comment: Unless otherwise specified, in math, we assume $\log$ is $\log_e$

Comment: ok I will take a look at it and ask you if I do not understand anything :)

Comment: Is it (ln(ak))/x or ln((ak)/x)?

Comment: Btw why $a_k^{1/x}\sim1+\log(a_k)/x$ as $x\to\infty$ ?

Comment: Using Taylor Series, $a_k^{1/x}=e^{\log(a_k)/x}=1+\log(a_k)/x+O\!\left(1/x^2\right)$

Comment: I have not learned Taylor Series. Can you explain me why $e^{\log(a_k)/x}=1+\log(a_k)/x+O\!\left(1/x^2\right)$?

Comment: I see that you don't want to use Taylor Series or L'Hospital, but one needs to use something to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x\left(a_k^{1/x}-1\right)=\log(a_k)$

Comment: I know how to show that, but what do I do after?

Comment: @OvyOvy: I have changed the answer to use the definition of the derivative instead of Taylor or L'Hospital. Is that better?

Comment: Yeah I understood how you solved it. Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x \to \infty}\pars{a_{1}^{1/x} + \cdots a_{n}^{1/x} \over
b_{1}^{1/x} + \cdots b_{n}^{1/x}}^{x} =
\exp\pars{\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\bracks{\ln\pars{a_{1}^{x} + \cdots + a_{n}^{x}} - \ln\pars{b_{1}^{x} + \cdots + b_{n}^{x}}\over x}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\exp\pars{\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
{a_{1}^{x}\ln\pars{a_{1}} + \cdots + a_{n}^{x}\ln\pars{a_{n}} \over
a_{1}^{x} + \cdots + a_{n}^{x}} -
{b_{1}^{x}\ln\pars{b_{1}} + \cdots + b_{n}^{x}\ln\pars{b_{n}} \over
b_{1}^{x} + \cdots + b_{n}^{x}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\exp\pars{\bracks{%
{\ln\pars{a_{1}} + \cdots + \ln\pars{a_{n}} \over n} -
{\ln\pars{b_{1}} + \cdots + \ln\pars{b_{n}} \over n}}} =
\exp\pars{{1 \over n}\ln\pars{a_{1} \ldots a_{n} \over b_{1} \ldots b_{n}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{%
\pars{a_{1} \cdots a_{n} \over b_{1} \cdots b_{n}}^{1/n}}}
\end{align}

Comment: There's a mistake there. Consider $(1^{1/x} + 1^{1/x} )^x = 2^x \to \infty.$

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for your remark. $\color{#f00}{Fixed}$. That is the reason the question consider a  quotient. We should always check particular cases as you wisely did it. Thanks.